# Is there a free walking tour in Honolulu?

Tags: tours, walking, hawaii, honolulu

I've seen mentions that some hotels sponsor a free walking tour, but can't find any actual details on it.  Does one exist?

Ideally I'd like to see the old buildings - the palace and so on, but even an informative tour around the beaches - Waikiki etc, maybe Diamond head, would be fantastic.

Comment: Are you looking for guided or not?

Comment: Prefer guided, but ultimately not essential.

Comment: not sure if this is legit, but came across http://www.legacyofhawaii.com/#!free-walking-tour/cnlw

Comment: @EdmundYeung99 you could put that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as they say: ["There is an app for that"](http://can-do.honolulu.gov/apps/11).  There is apparently an application for iOS that can provide you with self-guided tour of Honolulu.

There is also another [self-guided walking tour of downtown Honolulu](http://www.aloha-hawaii.com/oahu/honolulu/).

All of the guided tours of Honolulu would actually require people to pay but it may be possible that the hotels would offer discounts or even pick up the tab for that but this would have to be investigated locally when you check in.

As far as Waikiki is concerned [Frommer's](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/oahu/0009010008.html) gives a few but with no indication if someone will guide you through the tour.

Comment: Pity I only have Android, but that may be useful for others coming to this page in future.  I'll still wait for an answer regarding free guided ones, as it certainly sounds like they exist on some pages.  Otherwise after I've been (argh, less than two weeks from now!) if there wasn't one there I'll accept this answer :)

Comment: @MarkMayo Just went through a website of http://www.hyattregencywaikiki.com and  they don't have anything listed